# More efficient way to do double summation in python?

Tags: python

I have the following double summation:

[image]

And (using `gurobipy` package) I have the following code:

```
quicksum(quicksum(np.dot(C[t, v], x[t, v]) for v in V) for t in T)
```

Note that `quicksum` is just the same thing as `sum` in standard Python but faster for LP/Gurobi stuff. `np.dot` is numpy dot product. `C` and `x` are two dictionaries with tuples `(t, v)` as keys.

Clearly this runs in O(|T| * |V|) time without even considering time complexity of things like `np.dot`. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Are ctv and xtv actually matrices? If not, why use `np.dot` instead of just `*` or `np.multiply`? And if they're not matrices, the result of `np.dot` would just be a scalar value anyway, so wouldn't `sum` be faster than `quicksum` considering that you're just summing simple types? In fact, your solution could be `sum(C[t, v] * x[t, v] for v in V for t in T)`?

Comment: Are all the `C` entries the same shape as each other? And all the `x` entries the same shape as each other?  If so it looks like you could define `C` and `x` as  two packed multidimensional numeric arrays.  Summation will always be O(|T|*|V|) but it could be done more efficiently with the right configuration of `numpy.einsum` (it lets you specify arbitrarily which dimensions map onto which others for multiplication and which dimensions you sum over).   Note also that with the existing formulation you can get away with a single generator:  `quicksum(np.dot(C[t,v],x[t,v]) for v in V for t in T)`

Comment: @Grismar based on my understanding, ctv and xtv are simply integers. However, my PI told me to use dot products, not multiplication - I don't know why this is the case... (in one of the proofs, c becomes a matrix of coefficients, in another part of the paper, it's represented just as distance...) Thank you for your solution though! I will check it out.

Comment: @jez actually all C entries and X entries are just integers (well, C might be a float, I don't have access to the actual data right now). Also, I'm not too experienced in python - could you elaborate why we can use just a single generator?

Comment: You can use a single generator as the sum of sums of whatever you're summing is going to be the same as one super-sum of all the summed elements (as the operation is non-associative and commutative)